# How do I extract everything to the left of an @ in python using string indexing?

Tags: python, string

trying to take a user's email address input and print out the website in their address.

```
email=input('What is your email address?')
website=email[40:]


print(website)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
user, at, domain = email.partition("@")
```

Now `user` is the user name, `at` is the @ symbol, and `domain` is the domain name.

If there is no `@` symbol, `at` and `domain` will be empty strings. You could test for this and change `domain` to a default value:

```
at, domain = at or "@", domain or "gmail.com"
```

Or just issue an error message.

Answer (score 1):

Split once on the `@` sign and take the last element:

```
website = email.split('@', 1)[-1]
```

This works even if there is no `@` sign in the input string.

Answer (score 0):

I think this would work best:

```
out=email.split('@')
try:
    print(out[1])
except IndexError:
    print('Invalid email address!')
```

Answer (score 0):

This will explode if the address is ill-formed: `server = email.split('@')[1]`. Catch the exception with `rescue`, and report the error back to the user.

And it's not a "website" it's a "server". A website is just one of many services you can put on a server.

Comment: It's not a server, actually, it's a domain name. There's no requirement that there actually be a server of that name for the e-mail to work.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> email=input('What is your email address?')
What is your email address?me@somewhere.com
>>> i = email.index("@")
>>> i
2
>>> email[i+1:]
'somewhere.com'
>>> email.split("@")[1]
'somewhere.com'
>>> email.partition("@")[-1]
'somewhere.com'
```